# Using Ternary operation in the if condition - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to check to find out whether or not `numberOfItemsPerSection` is bigger than 3 in the if condition. It always returns true. Then I decided to debug.

How is it possible that `indexPath.row` equals to 1 and `numberOfItemsPerSection` = 20 and it goes into to the if condition.

What am I doing wrong by using the following ternary operator?

```
if(indexPath.row == (numberOfItemsPerSection > 3) ? (numberOfItemsPerSection-4) : numberOfItemsPerSection)
{


}
```

Comment: in this operation the indexPath.row == (numberOfItemsPerSection > 3) this will resolve to true or false. which will leave either (numberOfItemsPerSection-4) or numberOfItemsPerSection in the if condition. which i think is greater than 0 thats why its entering in the if condition.

Comment: you are eventually checking (numberOfItemsPerSection-4) or numberOfItemsPerSection in your if. have a look at this ternary operator on google you will find whats wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parenthesises to resolve priority. Change the condition by below way. Just cover your turnery condition with parenthesis. It will resolve the turnery operator first and then it will compare it to indexPath.row.

```
if(indexPath.row == ((numberOfItemsPerSection > 3) ? (numberOfItemsPerSection-4) : numberOfItemsPerSection))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSInteger desiredRow = numberOfItemsPerSection > 3 ? (numberOfItemsPerSection-4) : numberOfItemsPerSection;
if(indexPath.row == desiredRow) { ... // do your coding }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
if (indexPath.row == (numberOfItemsPerSection > 3 ? numberOfItemsPerSection - 4 : numberOfItemsPerSection)) { ... }
```

Or if you don't want to hurt your eyes:

```
BOOL desiredRow = numberOfItemsPerSection > 3 ? numberOfItemsPerSection - 4 : numberOfItemsPerSection;
if (indexPath.row == desiredRow) { ... }
```